# How to find the variance of the least squares method?

Tags: normal-distribution, bayesian, least-squares, variance

I'm using Bayesian Inference to find the parameters for a specific formula $ Y=a*X^b$.

Then; $Y$ ~ $N(a*X^b, variance)$

First I want to use least squares method to find the parameters $a$ en $b$.Then I want to find the variance that belong to these parameters, like the formula above.

Does anyone have an idea how to find that variance?

I know the variance should be
$ \frac {\sum(x_i - mean)^2}  N$

But what should be $x_i$ and what is the mean?

Comment: The $x_i$ are your datapoints and the mean should be what you expect. Thus in this case $y(x_i) = a x_i^b$.

Comment: @StanTendijck So it will be $ \frac {\sum (expected Y - calculated a x_i ^b)^2 } N $ ?

Comment: Yes and as Ahmad points out, you need to divide by $N-2$ instead of $N$ to be precise. Since take for example $2$ datapoints, then any model can fit them perfectly.

Comment: @StanTendijck Okay, but I get different outcomes between your idea and Ahmads idea. Which is the correct one?

Comment: He calculates the variance of the logarithm of $Y$ if that is what you mean.

Comment: No because you take logarithms on both sides, shouldn't this be of influence. So that's why I'm wondering why your method is different than his?

Comment: That's what I am saying. You calculate $V(Y)$ and he $V(\log Y)$. Two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Taking logarithms on both sides, we get
\begin{equation}
 \log Y_i = \log a X_i^b = \log a + b \log X_i
\end{equation}
Calling
\begin{align}
 y_i &= \log Y_i \\
 x_i &= \log X_i \\
 \beta_0 &= \log a \\
 \beta_1 &= b
\end{align}
You'd get a linear model
\begin{equation}
 y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i
\end{equation}
in which you could apply simple linear regression to estimate $\beta_0,\beta_1$,denoted as $\hat{\beta}_0 , \hat{\beta}_1$. Your variance could be estimated as $$variance =\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{[y_i - (\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_i)]^2}{n-2}$$
or you could divide by $n$ for large $n$.

Comment: Where did the power 2 go in your variance equation?

Comment: typo edited ...